# Start VirtualBox and VM in Windows boot

Tags: virtualbox, windows-server-2016

I am running VirtualBox in [Windows Server 2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2016). I want to start both VirtualBox and a VM within that when Windows boots. I have seen some posts about starting VirtualBox on Windows boot, but I have not gotten that to work. And even if I did, that would not autostart the VM. I feel there must be a way to do this, but hours of googling has not found the way.

Comment: Best place to find most up to date answer https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/autostart.html (adjust for latest version).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I have an example of how to autostart a VirtualBox VM during Windows startup. I'm running Windows 10, but it shouldn't be much different on Windows Server 2016.

The startup folder on my system is:

> C:\Users\chriwill\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

In that folder I placed a batch file `kubuntu.bat` with following content:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm kubuntu --type headless
```

In my example the VM is named `kubuntu`. You'll have to change it for your instance.

***Addon:***

If you need help finding the startup folder on your windows instance press keys <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter `shell:startup`.

Reference: *[8.19. VBoxManage startvm](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-startvm)*

Comment: Does the VM shutdown properly when Windows shuts down or reboots?

Comment: I've found the VM will shut down (hey that's two words there) properly when I bounce or kill the host box properly, yes.  The main hurdle is the (re)start on boot afterward.

Comment: I agree with @DeeJayh, however link provided by him seems to be wrong.

Comment: This starts the VM when the user 'chriwill' logs in, not at boot as asked, nor when another user logs in. What you need is a solution that runs as a service (check below, in the less voted up answers) (and yes, I know I'm commenting on something from 5 years ago).

Comment: I agree that using Task Manager is the "right" way, but putting stuff in starttup is pretty traditional.    Plus, I'm upvoting this answer just for the shell:startup hack!  never knew that... it's always been a pain to find the startup folder!

Answer (score 30):

This worked for me.

1. Create a shortcut.

   - Open VirtualBox
   - highlight the VM you want to startup
   - click "Machine" → "Create Shortcut on Desktop"
2. Add to Windows startup

   - *Start* → *Run*
   - type in "shell:startup"
   - copy & paste the shortcut in here.

Comment: its nice, if this could be turned into headless then it would be amazing.

Comment: Perfect  This worked perfectly for me. I was not able to get my VM running with the accepted answer, but this solved it!

Comment: Perfect and simple. The best thing.

Answer (score 21):

Oracle VirtualBox 6.1.16 supports [automatic startup via a Windows service](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#autostart) without third-party scripts or software. These were the steps I followed. Replace my login with yours throughout.

1. Create a configuration file in `C:\Users\Tim\.VirtualBox\autostart.properties`:

   ```ini
   # Default policy is to deny starting a VM, the other option is "allow".
   default_policy = deny

   # Tim is allowed to start virtual machines but starting them
   # will be delayed for 10 seconds
   Tim = {
       allow = true
       startup_delay = 10
   }
   ```
2. Add an environment variable for `VBOXAUTOSTART_CONFIG` and set it to `C:\Users\Tim\.VirtualBox\autostart.properties`.
3. Create the autostart service from an administrative PowerShell window:

   ```
   cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox"
   .\VBoxAutostartSvc.exe install --user=Tim
   .\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Peppermint x64" --autostart-enabled on
   ```
4. Find the *VirtualBox Autostart Service tim@tim-pc* service from the *[Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service#Services_snap-in)* application.
5. Ensure the service login is your local login as configured above.
6. Ensure that automatic startup is enabled.
7. Start the service.
8. Check for errors in the Windows *[Event Viewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer)* application under application logs. Error descriptions are under the "Details" tab.

Comment: The VBoxAutostartSvc.exe binary seems to be missing from my VirtualBox directory. Any pointers?

Comment: I assume the line :
"# Bob is allowed to start virtual machines but starting them".  
should say Tim, not Bob.  But that's just a comment

Comment: @irdroid3 Thanks, I fixed it to read `Tim is allowed`

Comment: One addition: I could not get the service to start, it threw `error 31 - a device attached to the system is not functioning`. Solution: in autostart.properties, there *must* be an empty newline at the end of the file.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a service for it by using [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/usage). Example:

Open cmd

```
cd /d A:\programs\nssm-2.24\win64
nssm.exe install  kubuntu
```

Fill the forms:

```
# Application Tab

 Application Path:   C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
Startup directory:   C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
        Arguments:   startvm "kubuntu" --type headless


# Details Tab
    Display name:  kubuntu
```

Click *Install service*, and done.

Answer (score 8):

No. No. NOOOOOOOOO... 
Have you ever heard about [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)?? 
That's exactly what it is here for.

Startup folder? 
This is not a great solution for so many reasons.
The startup folder often not reliable, and if something went wrong you can't just check last run time, last state, etc…
Especially for this type of execution.

---

**So let's bring in a good, trustworthy solution:**

1. Open the Windows Task Scheduler.
2. To organize the whole thing neatly, create a new Folder under "Task scheduler Library" called "VMs".

   (Or what ever you want to call it...)
3. Navigate to the folder you made and press "Create Task"
4. Name the Task
5. Select "run whether user is logged in or not"
6. Go to actions and press "New"
7. Action: Start Program
8. Program/Script: "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
9. Arguments: startvm *your_vm_name* --type headless
10. now go to "Trigger" and press "New"
11. choose System start and press ok
12. ***Done***

You can try the task by starting it out of the task scheduler via right-click.

---

So again, why use this instead of startup folder?
Startup folder works fine. But you MUST trust that everything is working fine as expected, and in enough cases it will just not, and you end up restarting your PC to try to fix it, etc... or in short it is just a huge PITA! :.)

Comment: This breaks the detachable functionality of virtualbox: https://superuser.com/questions/1570684/virtualbox-show-button-does-not-show-running-virtual-machines

Answer (score 6):

Scheduled task. Under actions, Program/scripts

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe"
```

Under Arguments

```
startvm Pihole --type headless
```

Comment: Is *"Scheduled task"* the actual name? Not *"Scheduled Task"* or *"Scheduled Tasks"*? How is it invoked?

Answer (score 5):

### Solution:

It is not possible to do what you are asking ***as a service*** without using a third-party wrapper (read: another point of failure) to your system. You ***can***, however, easily implement this as a Task via [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) that ***will*** run every time your system boots/starts ***before*** a user ever logs in.

Information on that can be found in my answer in
*[How can I run "Oracle VirtualBox (VBOX)" like a service after boot in fully background "Microsoft Windows (WIN)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017825/how-to-run-oracle-virtualbox-vbox-like-a-service-after-boot-in-fully-backgro/67305645#67305645)*.

Comment: easily the most straight forward solution and the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 4):

I needed a virtual machine running as a service—available from the network before user logged in first time—so [fanxings' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59432965/926540) was an almost ideal solution.

The problem was VBoxManage starts the virtual machine and then simply exits. So service manager tries to run it again. And again. And again…

I've worked around this with a small batch file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm zztop --type headless
pause
```

This batch file was then installed as a service using `nssm`. This solved the problem with closing the virtual machine using the GUI—e.g. for changing configuration—and prevented multiple error messages from showing up in the system log.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good choice to Add a Schedule Task. There is a plenty of options how it will warm up.

You can select run the task on startup regardless of user logins.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the virtual machine even without logging in to the system, you can use the [VBoxVmService](https://github.com/onlyfang/VBoxVmService) utility which runs one or more VirtualBox machines in headless mode as Windows services and starts them automatically on boot.

Answer (score 0):

- Open `C:\Users\userid\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder.
- Create bat file and type `C:\Users\userid\VirtualBox VMs\vmname\vmname.vbox`.

Windows should know `*.vbox` file extension to open with VM VirtualBox.
You can set by use "open with" on `vmname.vbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Two caveats for newbies like me when following official manual
(I tried both adding shortcut to *shell:startup* and [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), but I didn't succeed):

1. make sure the user/password exists in Windows 10. A user without a password won't install the service

   ```
   .\VBoxAutostartSvc.exe install --user=Tim
   ```
2. Use *netplwiz* to solve Windows logon. Uncheck the box "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer"

Finally, check again *all* "tim" was replaced when you copy the sample configuration file :-), I was stuck for hours to figure out why the configuration file couldn't be parsed.